# install virtualbox-4.1 beside virtualbox-5

Tags: package-management

Is there a way to have two versions of the same package (in my case virtualbox-5 and virtualbox-4.1) installed side-by-side? There seems to be a specific issue that I might only get resolved with a 4.1, but I don't want to remove the newer version, because other things work fine with that and I don't want to fix something that is working :)

Comment: If there is a regression or another kind of bug in VirtualBox you should let the developers know by filing a bug at their bugtracker. If you look at certain bugs you will find that they have a few undocumented features to disable functionality and analyze your problem.

Comment: I was trying to do an officially unsupported operation (install an OSX guest on an Ubuntu host), so it's not a bug really, it just used to work according to some people.

Comment: @fbence Pretty sure Mac makes that extremely difficult nowadays to achieve - it can usually detect virtual environments and will complain heavily or just not ever activate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to VirtualBox, I do not believe it is possible to keep two versions installed - each calls upon many things which are shared, and will have version conflicts with both installed.  (Including but not limited to virtual networking, which is utilized with the Virtual Machines to provide virtual network interfaces)

Some packages are capable of being installed simultaneously (for instance, multiple `gcc` compiler versions), as they each share different library sets that don't use the same resources.  There are some server packages that can be installed side by side (multiple PostgreSQL server versions, for example) as well.  However, I don't think VirtualBox is such a package.

Comment: And this is handled by the package manager? I mean if I apt-get a newer version of gcc the older one will remain, as opposed to telling me now with VirtualBox, that it will remove the other version?

Comment: @fbence I believe so, yes... I have not poked at VirtualBox's packages to compare situations, but it should not be installing them both at the same time, as it can cause some headaches.  I would be hesitant to install both VirtualBoxes at the same time either way - you could be in for some major breakages.